# Group theory problems.

Tags: group-theory

1. Let $A$ be an abelian group and $B$ a subgroup of $A$. Prove that $A / B$ is
   abelian. From an example of a non-abelian group $G$ containing a
   normal subgroup $N$, other than $G$, such $G / N$ is abelian.
2. Use the previous run to show that the order of an element $gN ∈
   G / N$ is $n$, where $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $g
   ^n ∈ N$ (and $gN$ has
   infinite order if no such integer exists). Give an example to show that the
   order of $gN ∈ G / N$ can be strictly less than the order of $g$ in
   $G$.

I already did the two demonstrations, what I need to give are the examples, but I have not been able to do them. Someone help me with the examples.

I used the previous exercise, skip that, it's from my list of exercises, but I already used that to prove it :).

Comment: For the example in the first question, what's the smallest non-abelian group you know of? Does it contain a proper normal subgroup?

Comment: And for the latter, what is the smallest and simplest group that has a nontrivial proper normal subgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use essentially the same example for both.  Take $S_3$ and $N=\langle (123)\rangle $.  The quotient is isomorphic to $C_2$.  It's abelian and, for $g=(123) $ we have $gN=N$, so the order of $gN\in G/N $ is $1$.